# Slice pandas dataframe by part of string value in column

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, slice

I have a pandas dataframe that contains a column with a 9 character string. I would like to find the rows in the dataframe that match the first 3 of the 9 characters in this string.

My current solution creates a new column in the dataframe that simply slices the first 3 characters of the string, but I would like to solve this without creating a new column (since I have to delete it later). I generally prefer not to alter the dataframe if I can help it.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

# sample dataframe:
cid=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
strings=[
    'tncduuqcr',
    'xqjfykalt',
    'arzouazgz',
    'tncknojbi',
    'xqjgfcekh',
    'arzupnzrx',
    'tncfjxyox',
    'xqjeboxdn',
    'arzphbdcs',
    'tnctnfoyi',
]

df=pd.DataFrame(list(zip(cid,strings)),columns=['cid','strings'])

# This is the step I would like to avoid doing:
df['short_strings']=df['strings'].str[0:3]

out_dict={}

for x in df['short_strings'].unique():
    df2=df[df['short_strings']==x]
    out_dict[x]=df2

# the separate dataframes:
for x in out_dict.keys():
    print(out_dict[x])
```

Output:

```
   cid    strings short_strings
0    1  tncduuqcr           tnc
3    4  tncknojbi           tnc
6    7  tncfjxyox           tnc
9   10  tnctnfoyi           tnc
   cid    strings short_strings
1    2  xqjfykalt           xqj
4    5  xqjgfcekh           xqj
7    8  xqjeboxdn           xqj
   cid    strings short_strings
2    3  arzouazgz           arz
5    6  arzupnzrx           arz
8    9  arzphbdcs           arz
```

I have tried simply comparing `==df['strings'].str[0:3]` but this does not seem to work.

Comment: Can you add the expected output to your question?

Comment: I've added the printed dataframes.

Answer (score 1):

For this type of operations we use [`DataFrame.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`GroupBy.__iter__()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.__iter__.html), indexing here with `Series.unique` is slower:

```
mydict = dict(df.groupby(df.strings.str[:3]).__iter__())
print(mydict)
```

**Output**

```
{'arz':    cid    strings
 2    3  arzouazgz
 5    6  arzupnzrx
 8    9  arzphbdcs,
 'tnc':    cid    strings
 0    1  tncduuqcr
 3    4  tncknojbi
 6    7  tncfjxyox
 9   10  tnctnfoyi,
 'xqj':    cid    strings
 1    2  xqjfykalt
 4    5  xqjgfcekh
 7    8  xqjeboxdn}
```

Comment: I should have been more clear - in my application I am only interested in a subset of the groups, and some of them will be grouped together. Thus I can substitute the .unique with the list of strings I am interested in. Additionally, some strings will be grouped together (ex: 'arz' and 'tnc' saved in the same dataframe/dictionary entry).

Is there a way to do that with groupby? (or perhaps better asked: is there a way to include an "if" statement into the groupby?)